# How to solve Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Could not instantiate tag for 'login': Cannot read property 'on' of null?

Tags: javascript, jquery, linkedin-api

Below is my code and I am facing this issue ==>Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Could not instantiate tag for 'log in': Cannot read property 'on' of null.

I can just put this code but still, I am facing the issue.
So please help me.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
   api_key: xxxxxxxx
   authorize: true  
   onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  // Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
  function onLinkedInLoad() {
   IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
  }

  // Logout user
  function logout(){
    IN.User.logout(onLogout);
  }

  function onLogout(){
    console.log('Logout successfully');
  }

  // Use the API call wrapper to request the member's basic profile data
  function getProfileData() {

   IN.API.Profile("me").fields("first-name", "last-name", "email-address","picture-url").result(function (data) {

    var userdata = data.values[0];

    $.ajax({
     url: "saveuser.php",
     type: "post",
     data: {"social_type": "linkedin","fname": userdata.firstName,"lname": userdata.lastName,"email": userdata.emailAddress, "profile_image": userdata.pictureUrl },
     success: function(response){

      console.log(response);
     }
   });

  }).error(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
 }

 </script>
<script type="in/Login"></script>
```

Comment: do you have a local copy of platform.linkedin.com/in.js or should you receive it with http scheme?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js"> I put this script only.

Comment: when does this error occur? on load or on a user event

Comment: This error occur on on load

Comment: It looks like LinkedIn dropped support of their javascript sdk and of their OAuth 1.0 login flow, I am not sure if this is causing your error but regardless it should cause some new errors, their new OAuth system docs can be found at https://www.linkedin.com/developers/

Comment: I am not sure if it's in the scope of your problem, but I would suggest Google OAuth: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent

Comment: ok. not an issue I will check thanks.